# Regular expression to match | but not ||

Tags: php, regex

My goal is to split a string such as, `a|b||c|d` in `a`, `b||c` and `d`.

I tried using several methods, but end up splititng my string in any way:

Lookbehind:

```
var_dump(preg_split("/\\|(?<!\\|\\|)/", 'a|b||c|d'));

array (size=4)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string '|c' (length=2)
  3 => string 'd' (length=1)
```

Lookahead:

```
var_dump(preg_split("/(?!\\|\\|)\\|/", 'a|b||c|d'));

array (size=4)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b|' (length=2)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
  3 => string 'd' (length=1)
```

How can I just ignore doublepipes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split your input according to the below regex which uses negative lookarounds.

```
(?<!\|)\|(?!\|)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/23)

`|` is a special meta character in regex which acts like a logical OR or alternation operator. To match a literal `|` symbol, you need to escape the `|` in your regex like `\|`

Comment: Okey, I get it, I needed to use negative lookarounds in both sides. Makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for splitting:

```
(?<!\|)\|(?!\|)
```